# Service is not injected in a Controller in Spring 3

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Fist time I will say, I am quite new to Spring...

I have a method that must be transactional, but are in different classes. These methods receive some parameters from an Android app. So, I wrote a GeneralServiceImp:

```
public class GeneralServiceImp implements GeneralService{

UserDao userDao;
VehiculoDao vehicleDao;
@Override
@Transactional
public String addUserAndVehicle(User user, Vehiculo vehiculo) {
    System.out.println("Method addUserAndVehicle() invpked");
    userDao.addUser(user);
    vehicleDao.addVehiculo(vehiculo);
    return null;
}

public void setUsuarioDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

public void setVehiculoDao(VehiculoDao vehicleDao) {
    this.vehicleDao = vehicleDao;
}

}
```

This is UserController:

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioControllers {

@Autowired

UsuarioService usuarioService;
GeneralService generalService;
@RequestMapping("/usuario/add")
@ResponseBody
public String addUsuario(@ModelAttribute("usuario")
User usuario,@ModelAttribute("vehiculo")Vehiculo vehiculo,BindingResult result){
    System.out.println("Petition received");
    if(usuario==null){
        System.out.println("Usuario is null");
    }
    if(vehiculo==null){
        System.out.println("Vehiculo is null");
    }
    try{
    //usuarioService.addUsuario(usuario);
        if(generalService!=null){
        generalService.addUserAndVehicle(usuario, vehiculo);
        }else{
            System.out.println("generalService is null");
            return "fail";
        }
    }catch (DuplicateKeyException e){
        return "duplicated";
    }
    return "ok";

}
```

And in the XML bean definition file i have generalService defined this way:

```
 <bean name="generalService" class="com.goatsoft.appark.services.GeneralServiceImp">
<property name="usuarioDao" ref="userDao"/>
<property name="vehiculoDao" ref="vehiculoDao"/>
</bean>
```

Thigs this way, the program enters the "generalService is null" if, and I don't know why! If you see, there is a commented line "//usuarioService.addUsuario(usuario);". That worked perfectly. Can you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only autowired UsuarioService.

And your daos are not wired up at all. So it should look like this :

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioControllers {
@Autowired
UsuarioService usuarioService;
@Autowired
GeneralService generalService;
```

Comment: Of course... What a stupid I am! I autowired generalService and its working now. By the way, i didnt need to autowire the Daos, and it did work. Thanks for the answer! I'll accept when the timer lets me :)